# Lodash: filter multiple properties

Tags: lodash

I am new to lodash.

I am having trouble filtering with lodash. I have a deep nested json object that I want to filter if productName = 'Lotto' and the board selectionMethod = "AUTOPICK"

When I try the solution below, it returns all results instead of filtering. I have tried multiple ways to do this but I always get all results returning.

Could anyone offer a suggestion?

```
var results = {

"buyTicketDetails": {
    "result": 0,
    "message": "Success",
    "product": [
        {
            "productName": "Lotto",
            "displayPromoMessage": false,
            "drawDetails": [
                {
                    "drawTypeDescription": "REGULAR DRAW",
                    "drawAttribute": "EVENING",
                    "drawStartDate": "2019-01-12T00:00:00.000-05",
                    "drawEndDate": "2019-01-12T00:00:00.000-05"
                },
                {
                    "drawTypeDescription": "SPECIAL DRAW",
                    "drawAttribute": "EVENING",
                    "drawStartDate": "2019-01-12T00:00:00.000-05",
                    "drawEndDate": "2019-01-12T00:00:00.000-05"
                }
            ],
            "board": [
                {
                    "boardType": "REGULAR",
                    "selectionMethod": "AUTOPICK",
                    "selectionSet": [
                        "2",
                        "4",
                        "10",
                        "12",
                        "17",
                        "31"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "boardType": "RAFFLE",
                    "selectionMethod": "SYSTEMPICK",
                    "selectionSet": [
                        "40001722-01"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "productName": "Encore",
            "displayPromoMessage": false,
            "drawDetails": [
                {
                    "drawTypeDescription": "REGULAR DRAW",
                    "drawAttribute": "EVENING",
                    "drawStartDate": "2019-01-12T00:00:00.000-05",
                    "drawEndDate": "2019-01-12T00:00:00.000-05"
                }
            ],
            "board": [
                {
                    "boardType": "REGULAR",
                    "selectionMethod": "SYSTEMPICK",
                    "selectionSet": [
                        "3440514"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}    

const filterCat = _.filter(results, { product: [
{ 
    productName: "Lotto", 
    board: {
        selectionMethod: "AUTOPICK"
    }}
    ] 
}
);

console.log(filterCat);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Pure JS.

You can do this with Javascript's filter function too.

filter function actually works on Arrays, so we use map loop to add objects into arrays first, then we use filter function to get only the data we need!.

```
let Product = results.buyTicketDetails.product

let getSelectionMethods=(index) => Product[index].board.map((d,i)=>d.selectionMethod)

let  getTargetedProducts =(Name,Method)=> Product.map((d,i)=>{
  if(Product[i].productName==Name && getselectionMethods(i).indexOf(Method) !==-1){
            return d
    }
})


let FilteredProducts = getTargetedProducts("Lotto","AUTOPICK").filter((d)=>d !==undefined)

console.log(FilteredProducts)
```